# spring boot security not configured properly

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to `Spring boot` and `Spring boot security`. However, using the existing sample codes, I had written a code which worked correctly. In my design, I had a separate page for my login, called `login.html`. Now, I have changed my design and my sign in and sign up are in a single `form` in the home page and it seems to be problematic.
Here I explain the problem in more details:

1. I open the home page and then click on the sign in button. 2) I enter the username and password and click on the sign in button. Then, I see the `dashboard` page as expected. So far, so good.

The homepage, looks like the following:
[image]
and here is the code for the signin/signup form in the `home.html`:

```
<form th:action="@{/signup}" method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="">
            
                    <div>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>
                    </div>
                <button type="submit">SIGN IN</button>
            </form>
```

Here is the `signin/signup` controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam("action") String action) {
    
    String act = action;
    
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("signup")) {
            if (userExists != null) {
        bindingResult
                .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                 "There is already a user registered with the username");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("signup");
    } else {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
    }
    }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("signin")) {
         modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", userExists);
         modelAndView.addObject("firstname", userExists.getFirstname());
         modelAndView.addObject("lastname", userExists.getLastname());

         modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage", "Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
        
        modelAndView.setViewName("dashboard");
    }
return modelAndView;

}
```

So far, everything works and after signing in, I am forwarded to the `dashboard` page which looks like the following:
[image]
Now, if I click on `John` which is supposed to forward me to the profile page or click on `submit` which is supposed to forward me to another page, it returns to the home page in which the user is NOTsigned in.
Here is the form in the dashboard which should call a controller method when I click on the `submit` button:

```
    <form  action="/addReview" method="POST" name="addReviewForm"onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="hidden" id="category"name="category" />
<input type="text" id="first_input" name="first_point" placeholder="Point 1">
<input type="text" id="seventh_input" name="seventh_point" placeholder="Point 7">
<button type="submit">submit</button></form>
```

And here is the configuration for the security:

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
           // .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/search").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error=true")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
}
```

I think the problem is with `.loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error=true")`, but I'm not sure. I don't have any separate login page.
In the meantime, the function `validateForm()` is properly called. Just the controller method is not called.

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance,

##**Update 1:**##

I changed and simplified the code to make it easier to find the problem.
Now, I have the following form in my `home.html`:

```
    <form th:action="@{/}" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>
<input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" />
```

And the following configurations:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
  http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/search").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
  .authenticated()
  .and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
  .loginPage("/")
  .failureUrl("/?error=true")
  .usernameParameter("email")
  .passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
.logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
}
```

And the following controllers:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam("email") String email) {

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
             modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", userExists);
             modelAndView.addObject("firstname", userExists.getFirstname());
             modelAndView.addObject("lastname", userExists.getLastname());
          
            modelAndView.setViewName("dashboard");
    return modelAndView;

    }
     @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

With this code, I can't even see the dashboard. Clicking on the `sign in` button returns me to the `http://localhost:8080/?error=true` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the security configuration, I will rewrite it using the lambda DSL and explain what it is doing.

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/search").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                    .successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .loginPage("/")
                    .failureUrl("/?error=true")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
            )
            // ...
}
```

This is saying that requests to "/", "/signup", "/search" are permitted without requiring the user to log in.
Requests to "/dashboard/**" require the user to be logged in and have the role "ADMIN".
Requests to any other endpoint require the user to be logged in.
This means that a request to "/addReview" requires the user to be logged in.

In the case you described, the user is not logged in, which is why they are not permitted to access "/addReview".
Spring Security is preventing the request from arriving at the Controller because there is no logged in user.

Spring Security stores the details of who is authenticated in the [`SecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder).
Looking at the provided code, the [`SecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder) is never populated, so from a Spring Security standpoint, nobody is logged in.

The "/signup" endpoint above is simply setting some fields on the view (HTML page) and not actually performing a login.

Since you have enabled `.formLogin()` in the configuration, Spring Security provides most of the login functionality.
You just need to POST the username (in this case email) and password to the [generated "/" login endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form) and the framework will validate the user and populate the [`SecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder).

```
<form th:action="@{/}" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" />
</form>
```

Then you can use the "/signup" endpoint only for registration, rather than combining it with the login logic.

You may also want to look into the [Thymeleaf + Spring Security integration](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html). This will allow you to get the username in your template without having to set it in the Controller.

```
<div>Logged in user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span></div>
```

I would advise you against disabling CSRF protection. This makes your application vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf). The CSRF token is [automatically included](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-csrf-include-form) when using Thymeleaf, so there should be no code changes required and your application will be more secure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your compleeete explanation :). I am trying to implement what you have suggested. The only point is that I still don't know how I can populate who has logged in. When I try 
" Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();"
in my controller, auth.getName() is null.

Comment: In which endpoint are you getting the logged in user? Is this after they have already logged in?

Comment: I actually tried it at the end of the login controller, but now I'm somehow confused. Because you said that I am using "formLogin" which does most of the thing for me and I see that even in your code, were are not doing anything on the backend side to have the user really logged in and you have also removed the loginForm. Could you please make it clearer how I can really have the user logged in?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "you have also removed the loginForm"? Do you mean the `formLogin` in the security configuration? I have edited my answer to include the `formLogin` configuration as well. To clarify how to log the user in: If you have a custom form (e.g at "/") that posts the username and password to "/login" and a user arrives at that custom form and enters the correct credentials, then they will be logged in. After they log in, if they make any requests e.g to "/addReview" then the framework will be able to detect that they are logged in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I meant exactly the missing formLogin in the security configuration.
However, it is still not working. I have deleted my forms and just copied your form, but I think the missing part is the controller part. What should I do inside the controller for login? I am now, as you have already mentioned, just setting the view. I'm not doing anything to make the user logged in.

Comment: In the Controller you only need to create the endpoint that renders the login form, you do not need to create the endpoint that handles the login, since that is generated by Spring Security. In this case, you are using "/" as the login page. So you need a GET endpoint at "/" that returns that login form, and then your form can simply POST to "/". I have updated my answer to use "/" as the login page. In short. your login form needs to POST to the same endpoint that is defined in `.loginPage()`.

Comment: I updated my post. Could you please take a look at that?
I tried to make the changes that you had mentioned, but it seems that I haven't understood something correctly :(.

Comment: You should remove the `createNewUser` method in your Controller. You do not need to create the `POST` endpoint for "/". It is auto-generated because "/" is the login endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and prompt replies. It works finally :).